# Formatação de indicadores do carrossel do bootstrap 4

Tags: css3, bootstrap-4

Por padrão, os indicadores do carrossel do bootstrap são estreitos como linhas, gostaria de saber como deixar bolinhas no lugar dos originais. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os indicadores (as linhas que você citou) estão dentro de uma lista com classe `.carousel-indicators`. Basta alterar as li's desse elemento para "bolinhas", alterando o `width` e o `height` em valores iguais e adicionando `border-radius: 50%` para torná-las redondas:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Os indicadores terão 10x10 pixels de dimensão. Se quiser aumentar ou diminuir, basta alterar esses valores.

Lembrando que se o seu .css estiver sendo carregado antes do .css do Bootstrap, você deverá usar `!important` nas propriedades `width` e `height`:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 10px !important;
  height: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Veja exemplo:

```css
.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 10px !important;
  height: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: foi muito útil agradeço :)

Answer (score -1):

Sobrescreva a classe
.carousel-indicators li

width: 10px;
height: 10px;

e adicionando um 
border-radius: 50%;

Você pode testar isso na propria documentação do bootstrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado :)